# Protractor test for click button not working

Tags: javascript, protractor

```
<i><button id="recover-credentials-submit" 
   ng-class="{disabled: disabled, &quot;btn-primary&quot;: true}" 
   ng-disabled="disabled" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">
   <span title="send recover email" 
         aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-key"></span>&nbsp;Send</button>
</i>
```

tried

```
var buttonsend =element(by.buttonText('Send'));
buttonsend.click();
```

but did not work

Comment: `var buttonsend = document.getElementById("recover-credentials-submit")`

Comment: Seems the button disabled ( `ng-disabled="disabled"`), so it can't react to your click.

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at HTML snip button is disable. Normal click will not work with this. If still, you want to click then you can use javascript executor to do this. 
ex.

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0[.click()', element(by.buttonText('Send')).getWebElement());
```